# TDD: test wait functionality

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, asynchronous, tdd

I have a class `Foo` with something like a locking mechanism. Let's call those methods `lock()`, `unlock()` and `waitUntilUnlocked()`. The implementation of these methods is not of interest, since I want to test them (TDD).

Now I want to write a test testing that `waitUntilUnlocked()` really waits until `unlock()` is called. The idea I came up with is the following:

```
@Test
public void waitUntilUnlocked_waits() {
    final Foo foo = createFoo();
    final long[] durationInThread = new long[1];

    foo.lock();
    inThread(() -> {
        durationInThread[0] = measureDurationOf(this::sleepSomeTime);
        foo.unlock();
    });

    final long waitingTime = measureDurationOf(foo::waitUntilUnlocked);

    assertThat(waitingTime).isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(durationInThread[0]);
}
```

Drawbacks: This works with `sleep()` which makes it slow. Also, I get sometimes strange results that the assertion does *not meet* (The sleep time was 500ms, `durationInThread[0]` was 501ms and `waitingTime` was 498ms).

Do you have a better idea for a *reliable* and *fast* test, not open for race conditions?

Comment: you cannot have any guarantee about exact timing

Comment: I know, that is because I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to write a test which will eventually fail if your locks were bogus, but there is no one single fast and reliable **black-box** test when it comes to synchronization. 
Imagine somebody else, a freelancer, was writing `waitUntilUnlocked()`. He decides lazily to write it as

```
waitUntilUnlocked()
{
    //haha I know they cannot lock for more than 10 sec, easy money
    Thread.sleep(10*1000);
}
```

Your test will pass. You are trying to test that the caller of `waitUntilUnlocked()` will wait ***forever***, which cannot be tested.

A simpler way to test that it is the combination of these two tests.

The first one is your test a bit simplified. It tests the thread wait indeed ***at least some time*** when locked.

```
final Foo foo = createFoo();

foo.lock();
inThread(() -> {
        foo.waitUntilUnlocked();
    });
long time_millisec = 100;
inThread.join(time_millisec);
bool success = inThread.isAlive();
```

It never unlocks. `time_millisec` is your parameter. No need to measure times.

The second one test that the thread make progress if unlocked. You could add a timer to measure the time before join completes.

```
final Foo foo = createFoo();

inThread(() -> {
        foo.waitUntilUnlocked();
    });
inThread.join();
return true; //success
```

You will execute anything after join only after `waitUntilUnlocked` has terminated.

**Black box testing shows its limits in your situation**

Comment: Thank you for your solution!